# How to test an Entity Framework Core database as InMemory with insert functionality for a large number of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

In one of our projects, we have a database with lots of tables and thousands of rows. For our integration tests, we want our tests to run against a fixed database state, e.g., 5000 rows, so that the tests are deterministic and always return the same result.

We've worked with a small Entity Framework Core InMemoryDatabases before, where we added like 20 rows like this:

```
private DbContextOptions<OurDataContext> GetInMemoryDbContextOptions()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OurDataContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "foo")
        .Options;

    using (var context = new OurDataContext(options))
    {
        context.OurTable.Add(new OurTable(){...});
        // ...
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return options;
}
```

However, in our new case, that's not going to be feasible with this many rows that should be derived from the production database. We need a good way to sync real data into our in-memory database. How can this be done?

Ideally, we would export relevant parts of our production database into an SQL script with the SQL Management Studio and track this SQL export in Git as part of our test code. As far as we can see, there is no *import data from SQL script* due to the fact that we can't run SQL scripts against it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/ sums the available options up pretty good, but I still don't know how a solution would look like in our case since we need

- the ability to anonymize data from a production database to a state that we can store in Git. This sync should be done if we want it to, so explicitly not every time we want to run tests. We can't manually write inserts for thousands of rows.
- A way to reset the database to the stored saved before each test run.

Which in-memory database approach should we choose?

Comment: What is the purpose of your tests? Perfomances? Coherence? 
Be aware with in memory, as the documentation says, the EF in-memory database often behaves differently than relational databases 

* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: We want to test our functionality, either from C# code or from Selenium-based frontend tests. We do not perform any performance or stress test. `Be aware with in memory, as the documentation says, the EF in-memory database often behaves differently than relational databases` Yes, I've read that. That's one of the statements that confuses me in regards to which solution I should use instead or for which phenomenon I should look out for

Comment: I've added a bounty in the hopes of drawing more attention

Comment: Your question is rather broad and covers very different topics. You seem to ask how to anonymize data, how (when) to sync them, and how to manage test database state during test runs. Can you narrow it down to one question?

Comment: Okay, then let's focus on the main question (since I know how to anonymize the data and how to recreate a context, I just thought that if someone posts an answer he/she might paste a couple of more lines to make this a complete answer). The main question is how do sync data from production database into an in-memory database? My current best guess is that I write a code generator for C# code which inserts everything. That could be done via reflection but I just hoped that there would be a better way

Comment: Sounds like a good scenario for docker. You could create a custom image based on SQL Server that contains your db already with the expected 5000 rows you want. Every test run on your CI would start the container and your code connects to the instance there. You could also have another CI process which takes the data you want and puts it into the docker image and pushes to a registry, so you always have an up-to-date image ready for your tests to use.

Comment: These links should give you an idea how to prepare the image: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-79-saving-a-postgres-database-in-a-docker-image https://medium.com/@sharmaNK/build-postgres-docker-image-with-data-included-489bd58a1f9e
Another option is to have the .bak alongside the image and restore it as part of the container startup, I think that should be possible (never did but it kinda makes sense)

Comment: @jpgrassi Thanks for the idea with Docker and an SQL Server based image. This would allow us to persist the state of the database with an SQL script that inserts the data. Please post an answer as well so that you become eligible for the bounty ;)

Comment: Posted. Only because I think it's a valid idea (I did this recently, even thought about writing a blog post on it) so others can benefit. Also I wouldn't mind the extra fake internet points 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comments to an answer as OP requested:

As per the EF Core link you posted regarding testing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing) it's clear that using In-memory (or even SQL Lite) is not "recommended" simply because you are testing something which does not reflect your production scenarios. One might argue that you shouldn't test the db implementation but in reality most of the time it's necessary. For example, I want to test that a View I created is returning the expected results or a report is generated correctly, so I think using a full fletched SQL Server like OP is asking is a valid point. Another point is that using things like SQL Lite does not support well all migrations you can have using EF. I already ran with problems when creating indexes for example.

Moving on: One way you could try to solve this is by using Docker containers. You can run SQL Server in a Linux container [Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash). The idea is that you can create a custom image, based on SQL Server and inside the image you put your 5000 rows (or whatever data you want), build and push the ready-to-use image to a docker registry.

Then during the CI of your system where you want to run your tests with expected data, you start the docker container for the image you created and have your tests connect to that SQL Server instance (just need to map the ports to the host, usually 1433). This way you are guaranteed that your tests starts always with the same set of data.

As per building the image itself, you can do in many ways. You can have a CI itself for creating the image. It could take the data from somewhere, or have a small program generate it for you and put it inside the container. It could be a .bak file or a SQL Script with a bunch of Inserts generated by your program. Then when you want to have your image with "new" data, all you need to do is run the CI build. You can add then tags to the Docker image to make sure you can run tests against old and new version of the data as well which is cool.

Something to consider as well: You also might need to take care of updating the image when your DB changes (migrations) but you could also do that by either always creating the image from the latest version of your schema or apply the migrations using `MigrateAsync` during the CI process for the image generation. This highly depends how often your DB changes of course.

I did something similar for a Postgres database and these links helped me get started. It should be pretty similar for SQL Server as well:

[Docker Tip #79: Saving a Postgres Database in a Docker Image](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-79-saving-a-postgres-database-in-a-docker-image)

[Build Docker Image Postgres With Data Included](https://medium.com/@sharmaNK/build-postgres-docker-image-with-data-included-489bd58a1f9e)